# What does it mean when a type is a short?

Tags: c++

Why do I use short instead of int or char. And char is like an integer right? When I write a program I discover I can use it as a number...

```
char x = 1, y = 2;
cout<<x+y; 3
```

this returns 3 but i want to know what is the difference in int short and char now?

Answer (score 1):

`char`, `short int`, and `int` are all examples of *integral types*. They hold integer values in given ranges.  An integer is a number, so I don't know why it surprises you.

The difference between `char` and `short` is (usually) that `short` can hold a wider range of values. You can inspect the macros in `#include <climits>` to see what the ranges are for your compiler.

BTW, when you use `+` or any other arithmetic operator, the values are all promoted to `int` before the calculation happens.